# Item edit request in database design

Tags: sql, django, database

I'm developing simple CRUD app in Django. The app allows users to manage list of items. Let's assume that single item in database consists of following fields:

- ID
- Name
- Type
- Description
- Assigned_to (worker_id)

Beyond that there are two kinds of users - managers and workers. Managers can freely see/add/edit/remove/assign all items. Worker can see all items, but any change made (add/edit/unassign) needs to be accepted by manager.

Here's the problem. I wonder what could be the best way to implement this requirement. I came up with simple "ticket" system - every time worker sends edit request, ticket is created and can be reviewed by manager later. Ticket would be a simple object with following fields:

- Type (add, edit, unassign)
- New Item id (in case of add, edit operation)
- Old item id (in case of edit operation)

Along with ticket, new item would be created (with all changes made and additional is_active field set to False). When manager accepts ticket, this is what would happen:

- Add operation - is_active is set to True
- Edit operation - all fields from New Item are rewritten to Old Item and New Item is deleted
- Unassign operation - assigned_to fields is set to Null

The part that makes me worried is, of course, Edit operation. Rewriting all fields seems like hacky/dirty way to do it (especially if I would like to add m2m relations to Item). Do you have any better idea?

Comment: Add two fields: state and old description.  In an edit case, you can save the old description there, and replace with new description.  then set "state" in the state field.  From there, you can query all of those tasks in the "reviewing" state for managers so they can approve.  if disapproved, then in your view revert old description to current description.

Comment: There should be possible to edit all fields, not only description. Should I create _new field for each of them?

Comment: That's what I would do.

Comment: Your other option is to add effective and expired fields, and go vertical.